# Adicionar parametros em array JSON após serializar formulário

Tags: php, javascript, json, array

Após dar o seguinte comando em JavaScript:

```js
var dados = $("#form-historico").serialize();
```

É possível adicionar mais informações no objeto? por exemplo: Eu gostaria de enviar junto com os dados do POST alguns parametros para recuperar no arquivo PHP (tabela, coluna, etc)...

Tentei algo dessa forma, mas não deu muito certo:

```js
    var dados = $("#form-historico").serialize();
    myPost = {
        "dados": dados,
        "param": [
            {
                "crud" : "create",
                "table" : "tbl_historicos"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Enviando somente os dados serializados e dando um print_r($_POST), imprime dessa forma no PHP:

```html
Array
(
    [hist_peso] => dfs
    [hist_altura] => fsf
    [hist_pa] => sfsf
    [hist_fc] => sfs
    [hist_op] => fs
    [hist_temp] => fsfsf
    [hist_id_paciente] => 3
    [hist_id_usuario] => 1
    [hist_id] => 
    [hist_data_cadastro] => 
    [hist_prontuario] => fsfsff
    [hist_tratamento] => fsfsfs
    [hist_obs] => 
    [hist_reacao_alergica] => 
    [hist_doenca_contagiosa] => 
    [hist_mpa] => 
    [hist_etilismo] => 
    [hist_tricotomia] => 
    [hist_cardiopatia] => 
    [hist_protese] => 
    [hist_outras_doencas] => 
    [hist_jejum] => 
    [hist_tabagismo] => 
    [hist_diabetico] => 
    [hist_insulina] => 
    [hist_outros_exames] => 
)
```

Mas incluindo os outros parametros no array e dando um print_r($_POST), imprime dessa forma:

```html
Array
(
    [dados] => hist_peso=&hist_altura=&hist_pa=&hist_fc=&hist_op=&hist_temp=&hist_id_paciente=3&hist_id_usuario=1&hist_id=&hist_data_cadastro=&hist_prontuario=&hist_tratamento=&hist_obs=&hist_reacao_alergica=&hist_doenca_contagiosa=&hist_mpa=&hist_etilismo=&hist_tricotomia=&hist_cardiopatia=&hist_protese=&hist_outras_doencas=&hist_jejum=&hist_tabagismo=&hist_diabetico=&hist_insulina=&hist_outros_exames=
    [param] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [crud] => create
                    [table] => tbl_historicos
                )

        )

)
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar ou me dizer onde estou errando???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Página com formulário HTML e JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JSON | PHP | SERIALIZE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.12.0/css/mdb.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">

            <!-- Extended default form grid -->
            <form id="form-dados-paciente">
                <!-- Grid row -->
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="id">Código</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="data_cadastro">Data do Cadastro</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_cadastro" name="data_cadastro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="nome_paciente">Nome Paciente</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_paciente" name="nome_paciente">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="data_nascimento">Data de Nascimento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_nascimento" name="data_nascimento">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="sexo">Sexo</label>
                        <select class="browser-default custom-select form-control" id="exo" name="sexo">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="nome_mae">Nome da Mãe</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control nome-proprio" id="nome_mae" name="nome_mae">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Grid row -->
                <button class="btn-enviar btn btn-info justify-content-center">Enviar</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Extended default form grid -->

        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    <script>

        $(".btn-enviar").click(function () {
            
            //serializando os dados do formulário
            var dados = $("#form-dados-paciente").serializeArray();
            
            //criando o objeto JSON com os parametros
            var param = {
                "param" : {
                    "option" : "gravar",
                    "tabela" : "tbl_pacientes",
                    "coluna" : "id",
                    "switch" : "editar-paciente"
                }
            };
            
            //fazendo chamada AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                
                //usando $.param para enviar em formato de array
                //e concatenando os objetos DADOS e PARAMETROS
                data: $.param(dados) + "&" + $.param(param),
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    </script>

</html>
```

No arquivo **ajax.php**:

- Recuperei e atribui os dados do POST em uma variável **$arrPosts**

```html
    //recuperando e atribuindo os dados do POST a variável
    $arrPosts = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

- Criei uma função para limpar os parametros e criar um novo array somente com os dados do formulário

```html
//chamando a função para limpar os dados dos parametros
//e passando a variável com os dados do POST como parametro
$arrDados = limpaDadosParametros($arrPosts, array());

//Função para iterar o array montar um novo array somente
//com os dados do formulário enviados via POST
function limpaDadosParametros($arrPosts, $arrDados) {
    foreach ($arrPosts as $key => $value) {
        if (($key != "param")) {
            $arrDados[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arrDados;
}
```

- Imprimindo os novos arrays

```html
    echo '<br>Dados Form';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrDados);//imprimindo os dados do novo array
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<br>Parametros';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrPosts['param']);//imprimindo os dados de parametros
    echo '</pre>';
```

Obtive os valores esperados:

```html
Dados Form
Array
(
    [id] => 000014
    [data_cadastro] => 20/09/2019 10:36:24
    [nome_paciente] => Marcio da Silva Pereira
    [cpf] => 632.154.587-88
    [data_nascimento] => 15/03/1988
    [sexo] => Masculino
    [nome_mae] => Marcia da Silva Pereira
    [telefone] => (15) 3217-7083
)

Parametros
Array
(
    [option] => gravar
    [tabela] => tbl_pacientes
    [coluna] => id
    [switch] => editar-paciente
)
```

- Arquivo completo **ajax.php**

```html
<?php

if ((filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))) {
    
    //recuperando e atribuindo os dados do POST a variável
    $arrPosts = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    //chamando a função para limpar os dados dos parametros
    //e passando a variável com os dados do POST como parametro
    $arrDados = limpaDadosParametros($arrPosts, array());

    echo '<br>Dados Form';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrDados);//imprimindo os dados do novo array
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<br>Parametros';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrPosts['param']);//imprimindo os dados de parametros
    echo '</pre>';
}

//Função para iterar o array montar um novo array somente
//com os dados do formulário enviados via POST
function limpaDadosParametros($arrPosts, $arrDados) {
    foreach ($arrPosts as $key => $value) {
        if (($key != "param")) {
            $arrDados[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arrDados;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que esse exemplo serve pra você.

```js
//EVENTO PARA QUANDO SUBMITAMOS O FORMULÁRIO DE CADASTRO
$('#formulario-cadastro').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


  let origem = "pagina-de-cadastro";
  let formulario = $("#formulario-cadastro");
  cadastrar(formulario, origem);


});

function cadastrar(formulario, origem) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/cadastro.php",
    type: "post",
    data: formulario.serialize() + '&variavel=' + encodeURIComponent(origem),


  }).done(function(data) {


  }).fail(function() {

  });

}
```

- Acima, temos um **formulário** com ID "**#formulario-cadastro**". Adicionamos esse formulário a uma variável (chamada **formulario**).
- Temos também uma variável (chamada **origem**) que recebe uma String.
- Depois, passamos essa variável e o formulário como parâmetro para a função **cadastrar()**, e chamamos essa função.
- Dentro dessa função temos um **AJAX** que envia esses dados (tanto a variável **origem** quanto o formulário serializado) para o **PHP**.

No **PHP** você receberia a variável por **POST**. **Veja:**

```html
<?php

 $variavel_que_recebe = $_POST['variavel'];

?>
```

**OBS:** Se quiser enviar mais variáveis juntos, é só colocar como abaixo:

```js
data: formulario.serialize() + '&variavel=' + encodeURIComponent(origem) + '&variavel_2=' + encodeURIComponent(origem_2)
```

- Acima, você mandaria as variáveis **origem** e **origem_2**.
- Para receber no **PHP**:

```html
<?php

  $variavel = $_POST['variavel'];
  $variavel_2 = $_POST['variavel_2'];  
  
?>
```

Comment: Sim, muito bom este exemplo! Dessa maneira eu tentei e consegui, no entanto ele concatena mais informações no JSON. Eu precisava de alguma coisa que me ajudasse a separar essas informações na hora de recuperar no arquivo PHP, por exemplo: $dados = $_POST['dados'] e $parametros = $_POST['parametros']... Vou tentando aqui, senão vai ser via URL mesmo os parametros, mas acredito que exista uma maneira de fazer isso, eu acho!!! Mas valeu pela força...

Comment: Eu complementei a resposta. Dá uma olhada.

Comment: @RDamazio , nesse caso do exemplo, você receberia as variáveis, que você está enviando no AJAX, por POST no PHP. Tipo $_POST['variavel']. Não seria essa a sua necessidade ?

Comment: Sim, acabei de testar o seu exemplo, dá certo mesmo. O problema é que eu tenho uma classe que monta a instrução SQL com os parametros que vem nesse POST, nesse caso ele vai acabar montando esses campos adicionais também, que por sua vez não existem na tabela do banco de dados... Só se eu montar uma função para montar o array desconsiderando essas variáveis de parametro neh...

Comment: Mas você não quer as variáveis que chegando no PHP por Post ? Sua pergunta pareceu isso...

Comment: Sim, gostaria de enviar tudo via POST, tando os dados do formulário quanto os parametros para controlar no arquivo PHP

Comment: Então, isso está acontecendo com esse código. eu não estou conseguindo entender direito o que você gostaria de fazer com esses valores, quem chegam por post, no arquivo php.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil pra você, e respondeu a sua dúvida explicitada na pergunta, podes aceitar clicando no botão situado à esquerda da resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104424/discussion-between-jason-the-internship-and-rdamazio).